# How do I respond to theme changes in FluentUI Northstar in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui

I'm trying to use FluentUI Northstar for a React app for Microsoft Teams, but there does not seem to be a well-documented solution to work out what theme to apply, or how to respond when the user changes the theme.

As far as I can see, the theme is passed into the `Provider`, e.g.

```
<Provider theme={themes.teams}>...</Provider>
```

But while I could pass `themes.teamsDark`, for example, I am at a loss as to how to get this theme from Teams itself, or how to set up an `onChange` notification.

Is this possible, and (even better), is there any official MS documentation I have missed here?

Answer (score 2):

To get notified of theme changes while your app/tab is in view you can use the `microsoftTeams.registerOnThemeChangeHandler` API documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context#theme-change-handling

There is a useful community-built helper out there that can help you glue this all together:
https://github.com/wictorwilen/msteams-react-base-component